# MySQL Where to put in this statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

This is a bit beyond my skills and I had a lot of help from the good people at SO to get this far. What I need now is to put in a MATCH() ... AGAINST() but I don't know where to insert it?

The query I have is (and this is the short version):

```
SELECT
  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS i.idItems RowCount,
  i.* Items,
  # Create a JSON formatted field
  CONCAT('{',GROUP_CONCAT('"',Attributes.key, '":"', CONVERT(Attributes.value,CHAR),'"'),'}') as Attributes,
  IF (te.Key IS NULL,tp.Key,te.Key) as Type,
  tc.Value Color,
  l.* Location,
  c.Name,
  c.Mobile,
  c.Mail
FROM
  (SELECT ItemID, ats.Key, ats.Value FROM attributeStrings as ats
   UNION ALL
   SELECT ItemID, ati.Key, ati.Value FROM attributeIntegers as ati
  ) Attributes
JOIN Items i ON
  i.idItems = Attributes.ItemID
  AND CheckIn >= DATE_SUB('2011-02-16 00:00:00',INTERVAL 90 DAY)
  AND CheckIn <= DATE_ADD('2011-02-16 23:59:59',INTERVAL 90 DAY)
  AND Checkout IS NULL
LEFT JOIN Customers c ON c.idCustomers = i.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN attributeintegers atli ON atli.itemid = i.idItems AND atli.key = 'Location'
LEFT JOIN locations l ON l.id = atli.value
LEFT JOIN attributestrings atts ON atts.itemid = i.idItems AND atts.key = 'Type' LEFT
JOIN Lists tp ON tp.value = atts.value
LEFT JOIN attributestrings attes ON attes.itemid = i.idItems AND attes.key = 'Tech' LEFT
JOIN Lists te ON te.value = attes.value
LEFT JOIN attributeintegers atci ON atci.itemid = i.idItems AND atci.key = 'Color' LEFT
JOIN Strings tc ON tc.StringID = atci.value
GROUP BY Attributes.ItemID
ORDER BY CheckIn DESC
```

Now I need to get this statement in here somewhere

```
MATCH(attributestrings.Value) AGAINST("Nokia" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

As you can see there is a table called *attributestrings* and it has 3 columns: *ItemID*,*Key* and *Value*. I need to search the column *Value* for the words in the **AGAINST()** and only show results matching this and the other criterias such as the Date and Checkout above.

I tried to add the statement after the `AND Checkout IS NULL` like this:

```
AND Checkout IS NULL
AND MATCH(Attributes.Value) AGAINST("Nokia" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I had to use the *Attributes.Value* instead of *attributestrings* because it didn't found the table. This only resulted in the CONCATENATED column Attributes only contained the value "Nokia", even if there where more to CONCATENATE.

I hope someone are willing to take on this challenge...

// Tank you.

### [EDIT]

I tried to put in the WHERE before the GROUP as Tim Fultz sugested, but I get the error 
**Unknown column '*attributestrings.Value*' in 'Where clause'**

```
LEFT JOIN attributeintegers atci ON atci.itemid = i.idItems AND atci.key = 'Color' LEFT JOIN Strings tc ON tc.StringID = atci.value
WHERE MATCH(attributestrings.Value) AGAINST("Nokia Sony" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
GROUP BY Attributes.ItemID
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is put in the Where clause:

```
WHERE MATCH(attributestrings.Value) AGAINST("Nokia" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: As you can see there is no WHERE clause and the problem remains, where should it be inserted?

Comment: The WHERE clause would go right after your JOIN statements and before the GROUP BY.

Comment: It complains: *Unknown column 'attributestrings.Value' in 'where clause'*

Comment: @Max Kielland That's because you've *aliased* the references to the `attributestrings` table as `atts` and `attes`. Whichever of those you wish to filter on, you need to use the alias, i.e. `WHERE MATCH(atts.Value) AGAINST...`

Comment: Hmm, okay will try that at some point and get back... I have it working for now, but it would be good to get rid of the `HAVING` because it is MySQL specific.

Answer (score 0):

I think I came up with a solution...

I added another:

```
LEFT JOIN attributestrings fts ON fts.itemid = i.idItems AND MATCH(fts.Value) AGAINST("Nokia Sony" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Just before the `GROUP BY...` and then included `fts.Value ftsv` in the main select statement. Now I could insert a `HAVING ftsv IS NOT NULL` between `GROUP BY..`. and `ORDER BY...`

This gave me the result I wanted but the query starts to get a bit slow now...

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your query when you are assigning table names with as use every where in you query the name you assigned. Like you gave attributestrings as ats now use ats everywhere and this will work.